# While running npm run build getting error -Module Build Failed postcss-loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the below error for all CSS files wherever I am using in the code.
Webpack file configuration

```js
const { webpackConfig, webpackMerge, htmlOverlay } = require('just-scripts');

module.exports = webpackMerge(
  webpackConfig,
  htmlOverlay({
    template: 'public/index.html'
  }),
  {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    }  
  }
);
```

[image]

Comment: Webpack loader is missing or it’s misconfiguration issue

Comment: explan problem better for debugging

Comment: what version npm u using

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial its -6.14.4

Comment: First clear your syntax errors, and import files from node_modules with "node_modules/..." instead of "../../../node_modules"

Comment: @Freestyle09  There is no syntax error. It's a run time error when I am executing command npm run build. Even I am not using "../../../node_modules" in code anywhere. Thanks for your time